# Detect delegate parameters in runtime inside a generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, delegates

**[Simplified question]**

Given the following generic method:

```
public T MyFunction<T>()
{
// ...
}
```

And given that it's called in the following fashion:

```
MyFunction<Action<int, string>>();
```

How can I detect, from within the code in MyFunction what parameters T has (as it's a delegate)?

**[What are you trying to do?!?!?!?]**

I have a method with the actual signature of void `MyFunction<T>(Expression<Func<T>> delegateReturner);` that needs to know the parameters T has without actually invoking the method so it can generate a LINQ expression out of it.

Comment: You can parse the expression tree http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this won't help. The one place where the type is references is in CreateDelegate() within the expression tree, and in there they just use the same T. So all I end up with is a Type (which I already have from typeof(T)).

Comment: Okay - I take that back, I was able to look further into the lambda and find the relevant MethodInfo. However, that makes my solution weaker (since it requires more knowledge about the lambda expression). Is there no other way of figuring out delegate parameters from typeof()?

Comment: Using Reflection in a generic method defeats the point of using a generic method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code as long as delegates have a void return type like Action.

```
public static bool IsActionDelegate(Type sourceType)
{
    if(sourceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MulticastDelegate)) && 
       sourceType.GetMethod("Invoke").ReturnType == typeof(void))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: My code was not trying to figure out whether or not the type is an Action Delegate, as far as I can tell. It's trying to figure out the types of parameters.